# input different values in one line in C

Tags: c

I want to read from one line something like this "24a10b9100". The problem is that if I use one of these functions (`fgets`,`getchar`, etc.) at the end the input is just a string. But I want to read the numbers as numbers and the characters as characters.

Comment: look at [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/). try developing something with it and post if you have issues

Comment: The general way to solve this is to read a string, and then pull the string apart according to whatever rules you have for parsing the input.

Comment: Will it always alternate between numbers and a *single* character?  Will it always be 3 numbers separated by 2 characters?

Comment: Well the idea is to read numbers and characters in one line. Particularly it will be something like "number, character, number, character, etc". I don't know the length of input string and I don't know how many digits has the numbers. Thanks everyone for your reply

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sscanf` and the `%n` specifier to advance through a string. The `%n` specifier will tell you how many characters are processed by the scan. That can be added to `offset` to move through the string. It can also be used to detect when an integer should be split into two integers.
The scanset `%79[^0-9\n]` will scan up to 79 characters that are not a digit or newline.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char input[80] = {"24a10b9100"};
    char nondigit[80] = {0};
    int digit = 0;
    int thousands = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    int used = 0;
    int length = 0;
    length = strlen ( input);
    while ( offset < length) {
        if ( ( sscanf(input + offset, "%79[^0-9\n]%n", nondigit, &used)) == 1) {//scan for non digit string
            offset += used;//add characters used by scan to offset
            printf ( "not number %s\n", nondigit);
        }
        if ( ( sscanf(input + offset, "%d%n", &digit, &used)) == 1) {
            offset += used;
            if ( used > 3) {//scanned more than three digits, split the integer
                thousands = digit / 1000;
                digit %= 1000;
                printf ( "thousands %d\n", thousands);
                printf ( "number %d\n", digit);
            }
            else {
                printf ( "number %d\n", digit);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I run your code and works perfect! Ι was slow to answer because running your code and try to understand how it works and more specific how the sscanf works because i 've never use it before. But now everthing is clear. I really appreciate the time you spent for this. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you read it in a string then you can iterate over the string character by character and check each character is digit or number and then process accordingly.

You can also use `isdigit()` function In `ctype.h` to check character is digit or number.

or you can read the character one by one and see by ascii value that it is digit or character.

Comment: Thanks for  your reply! I already think this way but the problem is in that example "24a10b9100" I want to read the number 100 for example as number and not as a sequence of characters. In that case I want to read "24,a,10,b,9,100" in one line. The hard way is what you say because i will have to find the numbers that have more than one digit and transform them. I hoped in an easiest way..

Comment: That really a problem.
As you said you want 9100 as 9 and 100 i.e 2 separate numbers this is a problem, as you only know where to separate (application specific) and thus there's no easy way.
What can be of little help(not doing all the part manually) is `atoi()` function which can convert string to a integer value. (store the characters that you no's in a string and call `atoi()` to convert that into integer ).

Comment: Thanks for this function. When I solve the problem I am gonna definitely use it!